# Problem with disk space sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Im executing query but there is an error:

Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.User2User'.'IX_User2Id' in database 'MyDatabase' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full.

Is enabled autogrowth by 10 MB without any restrictions on size.

Thanks for any ideas how to cope with that

Comment: Have you checked that the disk the PRIMARY filegroup is on is not full?

Comment: sure, still more than 20 GB free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this physical disk is not full and you are sure that you have restricted the file size within SQL then I would imagine that you are using Express version.

Express Version has a 10GB Database limit.

[Compare SQL Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx)

Comment: no, the file already has ~50 GB and im not using express version